# MAC - How do I find and remove postgres server?

Tags: django, postgresql, macos

I cannot find a way to kill or remove my postgresql server.

`postgres -V`

shows the version is 9.5.3 but I cannot find the path file in my mac. I tried `lsof -i :5432` and the result comes out as below

```
 COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
 postgres 1403 jk0819    5u  IPv6 0x35013bd948ad16e1      0t0  TCPlocalhost:postgresql (LISTEN)                                  
 postgres 1403 jk0819    6u  IPv4 0x35013bd9438f8821      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

but when I run `kill -9 1403` it does nothing. Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you remember how you installed postgres? Homebrew?

Comment: I'm afraid not.. :(

Comment: you can try `brew uninstall postgres` and if you did use homebrew then that should get it